# FFmpeg concat demuxer and handling encrypted chunks

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, muxer

I'm trying to process a remote m3u8 playlist containing (a possibly encrypted) HLS stream. The output I'm looking for is a mp4 container with MPEG-4 inside.

The playlist is a result of an ended live stream and **may contain EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tags**. As I understand, there's no "built-in" way to process it and indeed, there are plenty of warnings like "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream" and the resulting file always has some playback issues.

There are a couple of options to "glue" it. On an unencrypted stream, I found [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) to produce the result with the least playback problems. The command is:

```
LIST=chunks.list; ffmpeg -loglevel 'debug' -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto" -i $LIST -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe -y output_concat.mp4
```

where `chunks.list` is something like:

```
file 'https://www.example.org/chunk1.ts'
file 'https://www.example.org/chunk2.ts'
file 'https://www.example.org/chunk3.ts'
```

Now, I'm trying to use concat demuxer to process encrypted chunks. I've tried passing `-key` and `-iv` options in different places and changing `chunks.list` to be like `file 'crypto+https...'` but it won't pick up encryption key:

```
Opening an input file: chunks.list.
[concat @ 0x7f9fb6800c00] Opening 'chunks.list' for reading
[NULL @ 0x7f9fb6007e00] Opening 'crypto+https://www.example.org/chunk1.ts' for reading
[crypto @ 0x7f9fb5700a00] decryption key not set
[concat @ 0x7f9fb6800c00] Impossible to open 'crypto+https://www.example.org/chunk1.ts'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f9fb5700780] Statistics: 5094 bytes read, 0 seeks
chunks.list: Invalid argument
```

Docs [mention encryption options for crypto protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#crypto), so it looks it's just a matter of passing these in a proper way.

When, instead of using concat demuxer, I try to process and decrypt only one chunk like:
`ffmpeg -i crypto+https://www.example.org/chunk1.ts -key <my_hex_key> -iv <my_iv> chunk1.ts` it works fine. There's nothing wrong with the key itself, I'm able to decrypt it with other tools (openssl etc).

Is it possible for concat demuxer to handle decryption? If so, where should I pass `key` and `iv` options?

Comment: At present, options can't be conveyed to the child demuxers or protocols from concat. On my to-do for when I have time.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the info. Is there a comparably easy way to accomplish this task?